# Confusion about result of overloaded assignment operator being lvalue or not

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03

I have some doubt, reading this paragraph from the "Beginning Visual C++ 2013" book:

> When you express the remaining assignment operation as the explicit
>   overloaded function call, this ultimately becomes:
>
> ```
> (motto1.operator=(motto2)).operator=(motto3);
> ```
>
> Now, you have a situation where the object returned from the
>   `operator=()` function is used to call the `operator=()` function. If the
>   return type is just `CMessage`, this will not be legal because a
>   temporary copy of the original object is returned **which will be an
>   rvalue**, and the **compiler will not allow a member function call using
>   an rvalue**. The only way to ensure this will compile and work correctly
>   is to return a reference, which is an lvalue.

The class `CMessage` is defined as follows:

```
class CMessage
{
private:
    char* pmessage;

public:
    void ShowIt() const
    {
        cout << endl << pmessage;
    }

    CMessage(const char* text = "Default message")
    {
        cout << endl << "Constructor called.";
        pmessage = new char[strlen(text) + 1];
        strcpy(pmessage, text);
    }

    CMessage(const CMessage& initM)
    {
        cout << "Copy constructor called" << endl;
        pmessage = new char[strlen(initM.pmessage) + 1];
        strcpy(pmessage, initM.pmessage);
    }

    ~CMessage()
    {
        cout << "Destructor called." << endl;
        delete[] pmessage;
    }

    CMessage operator=(const CMessage& aMess)
    {
        delete[] pmessage;
        pmessage = new char[strlen(aMess.pmessage) + 1];
        strcpy(this->pmessage, aMess.pmessage);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

along with `main` function defined as:

```
int main()
{
    CMessage motto1, motto2;
    CMessage motto3("A miss is as good as a mile.");

    (motto1 = motto2) = motto3;

    motto1.ShowIt();
    motto2.ShowIt();
    motto3.ShowIt();
}
```

Question: Does operator function really returns an rvalue or the book is simpy wrong about that statement?

My understanding is that code is flawed, because in final result, `motto1` wouldn't be changed, but other than that it is perfectly legal, because returned copy (involving a copy constructor) *is* a lvalue.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111905/c-is-return-value-a-l-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CMessage operator=(const CMessage& aMess)` returns by value. This means that a temporary object is returned and the value category of `(motto1 = motto2)` is *prvalue*.   Note that nothing is special about `operator=` here, it would be the same for any function returning by value.

> My understanding is that code is flawed, because in final result, motto1 wouldn't be changed, but other than that it is perfectly legal,

In ISO C++ that is true...

> because returned copy (involving a copy constructor) is a lvalue.

The returned copy is a *temporary object*.  The word "lvalue" is a *value category* of expressions; it is not an adjective that applies to objects. The value category of an expression consisting of a function call where that function returns by value, is *prvalue*, not *lvalue*.

> **compiler will not allow a member function call using an rvalue.**

In ISO C++ it is fine to call a member function on an rvalue.  I can't speak to Visual C++ 2013.

Comment: note: the [MSDN lvalues and rvalues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90831hc.aspx) page contains many basic errors in the descriptive text (although the code samples are OK), I would recommend disregarding it.  The [stackoverflow page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) is better

Comment: I confirm that code compiles fine under VS 2013/2015. Thanks for advice about MSDN and the link.

Answer (score 1):

> Does operator function really returns an rvalue or the book is simpy wrong about that statement?

Yes, this particular overloaded operator does return a value, so the value category of the call expression is a (p)rvalue. The book is correct about that.

> My understanding is that code is flawed, because in final result, motto1 wouldn't be changed

If the intention is to assign `motto3` to `motto1`, then yes, the code is indeed flawed. However, the reason that the book gives:

> compiler will not allow a member function call using an rvalue

Is not true. It is true for c, and possibly for pre-standard versions of c++, but not true for standard c++.